# Are TFS support questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I watch the Agile and Scrum tags for new questions and I frequently see questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844263/creating-storymap-from-tfs-on-powerpoint-slide) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842043/add-custom-state-to-tfs-2012-scrum-2-0-template)

This to me does not seem on topic for SO for me as it isnt a programming question. It seems like the user is asking for help on a specific tool which maybe used by programmers, but isnt about programming at all. This seems appropriate:

> Questions about general computing hardware and *software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used *primarily for programming*.

I also don't think it is the correct use of Scrum or Agile tags so I often remove them leaving just TFS tags in place.

My actions; remove the tags and vote to close. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this off topic for Meta or do you just disapprove of my actions?

Comment: People tend to downvote on Meta for questions they disagree with, rather than just for the quality of the post itself. However I think there's nothing wrong with your post here; these sort of questions are what MSO is for.

Comment: This question has come up again. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786742/code-review-information-tfs. The questioner wants more discussion (as though an answer from Oded were not sufficient).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mistaken.

If you read the help center document detailing what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you will find:

- software tools commonly used by programmers

TFS is one such tool and questions about it are valid questions. Including usage and support questions (as far as support questions - help in installing and making the tool work).

---

Now, the question itself is a resource question / write my code question and as such is off-topic, but the topic of TFS and TFS issues is on topic.

Comment: I am confused, because the page you posted specifically says, "directly involve tools used primarily for programming". TFS is not used primarily for programming

Comment: @DaveHillier - TFS is an issue tracker and source control system. How are these not used primarily for programming? If Git, Svn, Mercurial questions are on topic, so are TFS questions.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm conflating the issue. I'm not familiar with TFS and the questions I see are all like that one.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842043/add-custom-state-to-tfs-2012-scrum-2-0-template

Comment: @DaveHillier - It is a programming question. A poor one, but a programming one non-the less. TFS has configurable workflows - you can add steps to it (by writing code and integrating it into the workflow). It certainly falls under the tools used by programmers, if nothing else.